# Execute command before auto mounting a disk drive

Tags: terminal, hard-disk, automounting

I have many external hard drives that often I need to run `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdf2` on after coming from a windows boot.

I do shutdown windows, but still this error persists.

I would like to have this command run before the drive auto loads, thus enabling me to use the drive as normal.

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens if you have Fast Startup enabled in Windows (as it is by default in Windows 8 and 10).

When shutting down with Fast Startup enabled, Windows does not really perform the complete shut-down procedure. Instead, it ends the user session, minimizes its memory footprint and essentially *hibernates*. What it does *not* do, is the equivalent of properly unmounting any local filesystems. If Windows is the only OS on the system, that's not a problem; but if you're dual-booting, it causes the exact problem you seem to be having.

Disabling Fast Startup should elimenate the requirement to routinely run `ntfsfix`.

Answer (score 1):

While not a simple answer,you can add udev rules to accomplish this.

I looked around and couldn't find any NTFS disks to write an example, but the ceph project uses this for auto-mounting disks.

Their needs are far broader than yours but look through these files.

https://github.com/ceph/ceph/tree/master/udev

With the caveat that I am unable to test, the rule you will need to add will look similar to this.

```
ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}=="ntfs", RUN+="/bin/ntfsfix /dev/%k"
```

Comment: That was my idea, too, but I see the problem that the automounting has to be delayed somehow. I guess if the block device is opened by `fsck` then a mount would fail. Maybe the device name could be something which the automounter ignores and be changed after the `fsck` run is finished.